# Trigger background image at each new link

Tags: css, image, hyperlink, background, hover

I'm not a pro in coding and I'm trying to trigger a different background image that takes the whole page in the background as the mouse hovers each link.

Here's the code :

```
<div class="bloc-films">
        <a href="project/crepuscule.html">Crépuscule en Mineur</a><br>
        <a href="project/belabandonne.html">Bel Abandonné</a><br>
        <a href="project/alicia.html">Alicia's Dream</a><br>
    </div>
```

Here's the CSS

```
    .bloc-films {
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: 400;
font-style: italic;
text-align: center;
line-height: 200%;
position: fixed;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
top: 50%;
left: 50%; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML** Code

```
<div class="links">
  <a href="page-1.html" class="page-1">Page 1</a>
  <a href="page-2.html" class="page-2">Page 2</a>
</div>
```

**CSS** Code

```
.links a:hover::before {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.page-1::before {
  background-image: url("./img/bg-1.jpg");
}
.page-2::before {
  background-image: url("./img/bg-2.jpg");
}
```

Change the **background-image:url()** to your image path.